# C# infinitive task loop using Task<> class + cancellation

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, task

I`m trying to make a small class for the multithreading usage in my WinForm projects.

Tried Threads(problems with UI), Backgroundworker(smth went wrong with UI too, just leave it now:)), now trying to do it with **Task** class. But now, can`t understand, how to make an infinitive loop and a cancelling method (in class) for all running tasks.
Examples i found is to be used in 1 method.

So, here is a structure & code of currently working part (Worker.css and methonds used in WinForm code).

**Worker.css**

```
class Worker
{
    public static int threadCount { get; set; }

    public void doWork(ParameterizedThreadStart method)
    {
        Task[] tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(i => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => method(i))).ToArray();
    }
}
```

usage on
**Form1.cs**

```
    private void Start_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Worker.threadCount = 1; //actually it doesn`t using now, number of tasks is declared in class temporaly
        Worker worker = new Worker();
        worker.doWork(Job);

        string logString_1 = string.Format("Starting {0} threads...", Worker.threadCount);
        log(logString_1);

    }

    public static int j = 0;
    private void Job(object sender)
    {
        Worker worker = new Worker();
        Random r = new Random();

        log("Thread "+Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId +" is working...");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            j++;
            log("J==" + j);
            if (j == 50)
            {
                //worker.Stop();
                log("STOP");
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(r.Next(500, 1000));
    }
```

So, it run an example 4 threads, they executed, i got J==20 in my log, it`s ok.

My question is, how to implement infinitive loop for the tasks, created by **Worker.doWork()** method.
And also to make a .Stop() method for the Worker class (which should just stop all tasks when called). As i understand it`s related questions, so i put it in 1.

I tryed some solutions, but all of them based on the **CancellationToken** usage, but i have to create this element only inside of the Worker.doWork() method, so i can`t use the same token to create a Worker.Stop() method.

Someone can help? threads amount range i have to use in this software is about 5-200 threads. 
using **J** computation is just an example of the the easy condition used to stop a software work(stop of tasks/threads).
In real, stop conditions is mostly like Queue<> is finished, or List<> elements is empty(finished).

Comment: The problem isn't with the `Thread` or `BackgroundWorker` class, it's with your understanding of multi-threaded applications. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywkkz4s1.aspx) is a basic tutorial, work through it, make sure you understand the core concepts, and then approach your problem again.

Comment: What is an `infinitive loop` anyway? Do you mean infinite?

Comment: i'm already get the point and read that all, trying to solve it one last week. anyway. now it's about Tasks, now BGworker. and the problem is in that that i'm desribed. i mean, how to implement it in my situation.

by the infinitive loop i mean that worker.doWork have to execute a method in every thread infinitive amount of times until i'll use stop method worker.Stop in the Job() method in Form1.cs

Comment: `i'm already get the point and read that all` - No you didn't, because if you did, you wouldn't be calling `Thread.Sleep()` in your worker method

Comment: it`s just remains from some other variant, forget to remove.
sorry, but it doesn`t related to my questions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, get it works.

```
class Worker
{
    public static int threadCount { get; set; }
    Task[] tasks;

    //ex data
    public static string exception;

    static CancellationTokenSource wtoken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = wtoken.Token;
    public void doWork(ParameterizedThreadStart method)
    {
        try
        {
            tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(i => Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    method(i);
                }
            }, cancellationToken)).ToArray();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { exception = ex.Message; }
    }


    public void HardStop()
    {
        try
        {
            using (wtoken)
            {
              wtoken.Cancel();
            }
            wtoken = null;
            tasks = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { exception = ex.Message; }
    }
}
```

But if i`m using this method to quit **cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();**
Get a error:
when **Job()** method reach J == 50, and worker.HardStop() function called, program window crashes and i get and exception "OparetionCanceledException was unhandled by user code"
on this string

```
cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

so, whats wrong? i`m already put it in try{} catch(){}
as i understood, just some boolean properties should be changed in Task (Task.IsCancelled == false, Task.IsFaulted == true) on wtoken.Cancel();

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid all of the mucking around with tasks and use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "Rx-Main") for this.

Here's how:

```
var r = new Random();

var query =
    Observable
        .Range(0, 4, Scheduler.Default)
        .Select(i =>
            Observable
                .Generate(0, x => true, x => x, x => x,
                    x => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(r.Next(500, 1000)),
                    Scheduler.Default)
                .Select(x => i))
        .Merge();

var subscription =
    query
        .Subscribe(i => method(i));
```

And when you want to cancel the calls to method just do this:

```
subscription.Dispose();
```

I've tested this and it works like a treat.

---

If I wrap this up in your `worker` class then it looks like this:

```
class Worker
{
    private Random _r = new Random();
    private IDisposable _subscription = null;

    public void doWork()
    {
        _subscription =
            Observable
                .Range(0, 4, Scheduler.Default)
                .Select(n =>
                    Observable
                        .Generate(
                            0, x => true, x => x, x => x,
                            x => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_r.Next(500, 1000)),
                            Scheduler.Default)
                        .Select(x => n))
                .Merge()
                .Subscribe(i => method(i));
    }


    public void HardStop()
    {
        _subscription.Dispose();
    }
}
```